Movie / episode where a spaceplane is stuck in orbit
I remember seeing part of a sci-fi movie or episode of a series 15-20 years ago.
What I remember is an airliner-like spaceplane being stuck in Earth's orbit. There was a rescue attempt with a space shuttle connected to the spaceplane by a flexible tunnel to transfer the passengers.

This sounds like the 1983 ABC Sunday Night Movie, Starflight: The Plane That Couldn't Land.
It has the airliner-like spaceplane and a space shuttle rescue.




I saw this a few months ago. I would agree this is the answer.

Based on Thomas H. Block's 1982 novel "Orbit".

Funny how the Trailer spoilers the outcome of all plot points. Now i don't need to watch the movie ^^

@airace3 but you don't how it's gonna end!

That looks amazingly bad.

@airace3, There is a kind of movie where, if you've seen the trailer, you've pretty much seen every bit of it that's worth watching. (I wonder if TVTropes has a name for that yet.)

@Ohm'sLawman, Trailers Always Spoil?

@ Igby Largeman,  it is terrible.
